# generate csr with entry type: trustedCertEntry

Tags: java, x509certificate, x509, keytool, csr

I got two question regarding the Java keytool. Can I generate `csr` for `trustedCertEntry`?

I also executed this command:

```
keytool -certreq -alias mydomain -keystore keystore.jks -file mydomain.csr
```

for a trustedCertEntry but I get error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <mydomain> has no key
```

which means a `trustedCertEntry` cannot generate `csr`? Or I need to have something, or a key to generate `csr` file?

Comment: A CSR is signed by your private key; since keytool uses keystore files you must have a privatekey entry, which is a privatekey plus cert(s) _in_ a keystore file. A trustedCert entry is only a cert with no privatekey, and you cannot create a CSR using only a cert without the privatekey. PS ITYM 'command' not 'comment'.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have something, or a key to generate csr file?

Correct. You need a keypair. You can't generate a CSR from somebody else's certificate. Otherwise the whole X.509 system would be insecure.